# In ASP.NET MVC, can someone give me an example of Visual Basic code for HTML.HiddenFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC2 web application, and I'm having trouble getting the HTML helpers to work.  I prefer to work in Visual Basic, and I have not been able to find any examples in that language of, say, HTML.HiddenFor.  I have tried converting the C# examples I have seen but it's almost as though the VB methods expect different parameters.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ASP.NET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) contains many tutorials for both C# and VB.NET. And for your particular example of `HiddenFor`:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.Name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net has a different syntax for [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.Something)
```

Comment: I'd rather call this an *anonymous function* instead, but it is referred to as a lambda in VB.net... (and I know you'd agree)